# Oauth2 chrome extension different user

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

Can I authorize and get oauth2 access token in chrome extension for currently logged in user in gmail instead of chrome user.
Thank you

Comment: yes. is anything failing?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) for the user authentication.

> Use the [`Chrome Identity API`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) to authenticate users: the `getAuthToken` for users logged into their Google Account and the `launchWebAuthFlow` for users logged into a non-Google account. If your app uses its own server to authenticate users, you will need to use the latter.

Here are the five steps you need to complete for Google account authentication:

1. Add permissions to your manifest and upload your app.
2. Copy key in the installed `manifest.json` to your source manifest, so that your application ID will stay constant during development.
3. Get an OAuth2 client ID for your Chrome App.
4. Update your manifest to include the client ID and scopes.
5. Get the authentication token.

Apps can get OAuth2 tokens for these users using the [`getAuthToken`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity#token) API.

You can also check these tutorials:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)
- [OAuth 2.0 from chrome extensions](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/)

Comment: Can you clarify what Step #2 means? >Copy key in the installed manifest.json to your source manifest, so that your application ID will stay constant during development.